# Play audio from url discord.js v13

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

How do I play audio from a url with discord.js v13.

I used this code and it didn't work.

```js
const connection = joinVoiceChannel({
  channelId: voiceChannel.id,
  guildId: message.guild.id,
  adapterCreator: message.guild.voiceAdapterCreator,
})

const player = createAudioPlayer()
connection.subscribe(player)

const resource = createAudioResource(`http://www.site/audio.mp3`)
player.play(resource)
```

Comment: What is happening instead? Nothing at all? What event are you listening to? Do you have the right intents?

Answer (score 0):

When you use the method `createAudioResource()` you need to provide a `file://` or a `Readable`. In your case, you need a Readable.

To get a Readable from a URL, I used the [got](https://www.npmjs.com/package/got/v/11.8.3) module from npm, but the latest v11. 
You can install it with `npm install "got@<12"`

Then, in your code, import it and get a Readable with it:

```js
const got = require('got');

const player = createAudioPlayer();

// We get a Readable stream from URL with got
const stream = got.stream("http://www.site/audio.mp3");

const resource = createAudioResource(stream);
player.play(resource);
```